# Filter/sort array with multiple variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an array with a created date and an updated date. I want to compare these two values and show html based on which value is most recent. I tried this:

```
{% set list = myArray|sort((a, b) => a.updated_at ?? a.created_at <=> b.updated_at ?? b.created_at) %}
```

and then

```
{% for item in list %}

<html>

{% endfor %}
```

but it is not working. Does someone know where it goes wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Why don't you sort such stuff in the controller or any service, such that you could write a test for this?

Comment: By not working i meant that the html isn't sorted based on the date. the value 02-09-2021 is shown before 27-09-2021 (want to show most recent first)

Comment: I mean are you sure `updated_at` is a `DateTime` instance or just a string? As @NicoHaase said, do this kind of sorting in the controller

Answer (score -2):

Sort the result and return Boolean value after compare dates in the controller side should be quicker and better.

---

**Edit:**

There is one point that is left out to me: Twig is never parsed on the fly, it has generated a "pure PHP" cache which is used to actually render the pages. The Twig language is therefore only a syntax which, a bit like CoffeeScript or TypeScript for those who know, cannot be used directly.

So Twig is ultimately only a relative question of help and used as another abstraction layer to fix what we are missing with Php.

Afterwards, in terms of performance & speed, I honestly think that it is the covers of the models that are used, so it is negligible for loading and data used, so for Php side sorting is good for: *Large data and high cells number set* & *Faster initial page load.*
Twig side sorting is good for: *Small data and cells number set* &
*Slower initial page load*( which is slower than same when he begins load from cache).

It also seems to me that it is the pages that are cached, and not the templates themselves, so there would also be a mechanism that avoids the costs of including snippets.

**Remark:** Every browser has an impact to *sort* function too and could generate different results *(issue with same values see example)* on sort few years ago I got different results with a Twig version ~ 2.12 using **sort** in Firefox and Chrome, I take this example:

```
Tabs = [
  { n: "Xicor",   g: 10 },
  { n: "Din",     g: 10 },
  { n: "Nico",    g: 8  },
  { n: "Jankos",  g: 9  },
];
```

After using Twig sorting:

```
{% Tab in Tabs|sort((a, b) => a.g <=> b.g)|column('n') %}
    {{ Tab }}
{% endfor %}
```

I got this in Firefox:

```
{Nico, Jankos, Din, Xicor}
```

And this in Chrome:

```
{Nico, Jankos, Xicor, Din}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should it be quicker to sort the data in the controller?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Keep in mind that Twig is written in PHP and will use the same functions that the controller is using. Also, please explain how any browser could have an impact on such actions happening on the server.

Comment: " Every browser has an impact to this too" - what do you mean by that? The browser can **never** have an influence about how fast a script is executed on the server.

Comment: I edited my answer and explained  the impact of browser to **sort** function.

Comment: As PHP runs on the server, I cannot see any way that this sorting difference happens based on different browsers

Comment: Just tested out your snippet in [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/1x3sas) - Got the same output on 3 different browsers, as expected. Also you've mentioned you've used `sort` with `twig < 2.12`, which can't be true as `sort` was only added into the core at `2.12`

Comment: Yes it's 2.12 confirmed, but tests are made with old browser version.

Comment: Please explain how the browser could make a difference here. Also, as `g` is not unique in your array, stable sorting can not be guaranteed

Comment: I don't have the answer I just write what I got with two **old** browsers with Twig 2.12 using **sort** function.
This not the same case as Twig here, but with JS we have had the same issue _(before EcmaScript 2019)_ [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability) with older browser